# CSR Routing error when using loader in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, fetch, loader

I was playing with 'fetch' function with 'loader' in 'react-router' and encountered an error, and I have been trying to resolve it for three days, but I still haven't been successful.

Symtoms is like this.

1. When I call local json file through fetch function within 'loader' in Homepage, it worked successfully.
   But, I found the error only if I move from deep level page to Homepage ( '/events/event/1' -> '/') which trigger loader. But error disappear and I tried refresh then it was rendered well normally.
2. there is no error when routing from same level or lower element ('/events' <->'/')

and my directory is like this:

[image]

```
//App.js
import { createBrowserRouter, RouterProvider } from "react-router-dom";
import EditEventPage from "./routers/EditEventPage";
import NewEventPage from "./routers/NewEventPage";
import { EventsPage, Loader as eventsLoader } from "./routers/EventsPage";
import EventDetailPage from "./routers/EventDetailPage";
import { HomePage, Test } from "./routers/Homepage";
import Root from "./routers/Root";
const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: "/",
    element: <Root />,
    children: [
      { index: true, element: <HomePage />, loader: Test },
      { path: "/events", element: <EventsPage />, loader: Test },
      { path: "events/:id", element: <EventDetailPage /> },
      { path: "events/new", element: <NewEventPage /> },
      { path: "events/:id/edit", element: <EditEventPage /> },
    ],
  },
]);

function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <RouterProvider router={router} />
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

```
//Homepage.jsx
import { useLoaderData } from "react-router-dom";
export function HomePage() {
  const postings = useLoaderData();
  console.log(postings);
  return;
}
export async function Test() {
  const data = await fetch("./postings.json");
  const parsed = await data.json();
  console.log("fetch completed");
  return parsed;
}
```

```
//eventsPage.jsx
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useLoaderData } from "react-router-dom";
import EventsList from "../components/EventsList";

export function EventsPage() {
  //   const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const [fetchedEvents, setFetchedEvents] = useState();
  //   const [error, setError] = useState("");
  const data = useLoaderData();
  useEffect(() => {
    setFetchedEvents(data.events);
  }, []);
  return (
    <>
      <div style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>
        {/* {isLoading && <p>Loading...</p>} */}
        {/* {error && <p>{error}</p>} */}
      </div>
      {fetchedEvents && <EventsList events={fetchedEvents} />}
    </>
  );
}
```

I found that several hints to resolve this problem

1. This error happens only if I fetch local directory files. If I change only url in fetch function which makes all the code works, then the error disappears.
2. I've realized that this is CSR (Client Side Rendering) error. So When I refresh, it gave request to server and there was no problem. I think this bug only occurs in the CSR

I'm very new to this programming world so please help me

Comment: Most likely the browser can not resolve the static path "./postings.json" since your bundle gets compiled on the client side.  Does using "/postings.json" and removing the `./` work?